# Square Root Limit Proof

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

I am getting tripped up with the following proof.

Suppose $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $x_n\geq 0$, and $x_n\to x$ as $n\to\infty$.  Prove $\sqrt{x_n}\to\sqrt{x}$ as $n\to\infty$.

So far, I multiplied by the conjugate to get $\Large\frac{x_n-x}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}}$ but I don't really know what to do next or how to use that. I know I need $x_n -x \lt \epsilon$ .

Comment: Did you really want to say $x_n\to0$, or did you mean $x_n\to x$?

Comment: @NickPeterson Yes I meant the latter

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $x=0$, this is pretty straight-forward; I'll give you a hint for the $x>0$ case, though.

Let $\epsilon>0$.  As you said, you can write
$$
\lvert\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{x_n-x}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}}\right\rvert=\frac{\lvert x_n-x\rvert}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}}.
$$

And, as you said, you want to make this absolute difference less than a given $\epsilon>0$ by choosing $n$ sufficiently large. Note that
$$
\frac{\lvert x_n-x\rvert}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}}\leq\frac{\lvert x_n-x\rvert}{\sqrt{x}},
$$
since $\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}\geq\sqrt{x}$.  (But, we have the benefit now that $\sqrt{x}$ is a constant for fixed $x$.)  So, if you can find a way to make $\lvert x_n-x\rvert<\epsilon\sqrt{x}$, you're in good shape.  What assumptions have we made that will allow you to make $\lvert x_n-x\rvert$ small for $n$ large?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: First look at the case that the limit is equal to $x=0$. The assume $x\neq 0$ and find an upper bound for the fraction.

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}}$$